# Promiseで配列をreturnしたい

Tags: javascript, promise

お世話になっております。
Promiseの戻り値の扱い方を教えていただきたいです。

■やりたいこと
Promiseで処理した配列の値を取得したい。

■プログラム
外部JSONファイルに書かれた画像のパスにアクセスしてBase64Imageに変換（5回繰り返し）。←ここまでＯＫ
変換したBase64Imageの文字列を渡して（←今ここ）、PDFに画像を表示させる予定。

■できないこと
後述のプログラムで、
`myData`に、

```
img_image01:base64,iVBORw0KG(…中略…)'
img_image02:base64,iVBORw0KG(…中略…)'
img_image03:base64,iVBORw0KG(…中略…)'
```

といった感じで、Base64Imageの文字列は渡せているのですが、

```
console.log(resolvedata)
```

すると、

```
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved", [[PromiseValue]]: Array(1)}
```

と`Promise`でラップされてたものが出てきてしまいます。（マニュアルどうりですが。）

```
Array(1)
```

の部分だけ取り出して、配列として使いたいです。
例えば、

```
resolvedata['img_image01']
```

とすると

```
'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG(…中略…)'
```

が返ってくるイメージです。

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------
// Promiseで順番に画像を変換してmyDataに格納
// ------------------------------------------------------------
var resolvedata = getContent().then((myData) => {
    getBase64Image(myData[0]['path_img'], myData[0]['image01'], myData);
    return myData;
}).then((myData) => {
    getBase64Image(myData[0]['path_img'], myData[0]['image02'], myData);
    return myData;
})

        (…中略…)

.then((myData) => {
    getBase64Image(myData[0]['path_img'], myData[0]['image05'], myData);
    return myData;
}).catch(() => {console.log('error')});


// ------------------------------------------------------------
// 画像のパスが書かれた外部JSONファイルを取り込んでmyDataに格納　（Promise）
// ------------------------------------------------------------
function getContent() {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        httpObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpObj.open('get', '（任意のファイル）.json', true);
        httpObj.send(null);    
        httpObj.onload = function(){
            var myData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            resolve(myData);
        }
    });
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// ファイルを指定してBase64に変換 (then)
// ------------------------------------------------------------
function getBase64Image(imgpath, imgfile, myData) {
    return new Promise((res,rej) => {
        if (imgfile == '') {
            res();
        } else{
            var path = imgpath;
            var thisimagekey = 'img_' + imgfile.split('.')[0];
            var getimg = '(任意のURL)' + path + '/' + imgfile;

            var encoding = false;
            if(encoding) return;
            encoding = true;

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET',getimg);
            xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
            xhr.send(null);

            xhr.onload = () => {
                var array_buffer = xhr.response;
                Base64_From_ArrayBuffer_Async(array_buffer,function(base64){
                    var data_url = 'data:' + xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type') +     ';base64,' + base64;    
                    myData[0][thisimagekey] = data_url;    
                });    
                res(myData);    
            };
        }
    });
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// Base64に変換
// ------------------------------------------------------------
function Base64_From_ArrayBuffer_Async(ary_buffer,callback,increment){
    var dic = [
        'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P',
        'Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f',
        'g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v',
        'w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','+','/'
    ];
    var base64 = "";
    var ary_u8 = new Uint8Array( ary_buffer );
    var num = ary_u8.length;
    var n = 0;
    var b = 0;

    if(increment === undefined){
        increment = 10240;
    }

    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    function f(){
        while(i < num){
            b = ary_u8[i];
            base64 += dic[(b >> 2)];
            n = (b & 0x03) << 4;
            i ++;
            if(i >= num) break;

            b = ary_u8[i];
            base64 += dic[n | (b >> 4)];
            n = (b & 0x0f) << 2;
            i ++;
            if(i >= num) break;

            b = ary_u8[i];
            base64 += dic[n | (b >> 6)];
            base64 += dic[(b & 0x3f)];
            i ++;

            j += 3;
            if(j > increment){
                j = 0;
                setTimeout(f,1);
                return;
            }
        }

        var m = num % 3;
        if(m){
            base64 += dic[n];
        }
        if(m == 1){
            base64 += "==";
        }else if(m == 2){
            base64 += "=";
        }
        callback(base64);
    }
    setTimeout(f,1);
}
```

何と書けば、`myData`を取り出せるのでしょうか。
どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: `Promise`が非同期処理であることは理解されていますでしょうか？`resolvedata`をグローバル変数のように扱って強引に値を格納する方法も考えられますが、非同期処理であることを理解されてなければおそらく正しく扱えません(また実装としても好ましくありません)。最後に`.then((resolvedata)=>{console.log(resolvedata)});`とメソッドチェーンをつなげてその中で`resolvedata`として扱う方法が素直ではないでしょうか。

Comment: 非同期処理⇒「前の処理が完了するまで、次の処理を開始しない」ので、時間のかかる処理の完了を待ちたいときや、処理する順番が重要な場面で使用するものだという認識です。（あっていますでしょうか？）また、`resolvedata`のメソッドチェーン内に`resolvedata`を入れることができるのは知りませんでした。。メソッドチェーン内で処理が完了できるように試してみます。

Answer (score 1):

（下手な日本語で失礼します）

簡単に直すには、各`.then`をこう変えたらほぼ予想通りに動くと思います：

```
                  // v-- getBase64Imageを返します
.then((myData) => getBase64Image(myData[0]['path_img'], myData[0]['image01'], myData))
.then((myData) => getBase64Image(myData[0]['path_img'], myData[0]['image02'], myData))
```

そして最後にこうします

```
resolveData.then(result => console.log(result));
```

一番間違っているところといえば、`getBase64Image()`にpromiseを作って`return`しているけど、そのpromiseの結果を待っていません。`then`内にpromiseを返せば、そのpromiseの処理が終わってから次の`then`が実行されます。

少し付け加えますと、以上のコードをもう少しきれいに書く方法があります。

とても似た部分を５回繰り返していますが、`Promise.all`を使うことで、配列をもう少し配列っぽく扱って、並列処理ができます。（そして並列処理のおかげで、少し早くなる可能性もあります）

```
getContent().then((myData) =>
    // 全部のgetbase64Imageを待つ
    Promise.all([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(num => 
        getBase64Image(myData[0]['path_img'], myData[0]['image0' + num], myData)
    ))
    .then(() => myData)
).then((myData) => {
    console.log(myData);
});
```